# Current RDBMS options in the cloud

Tags: cloud-service, mysql

We currently have a MySQL installation that, because "it just works" has not been given the attention that it should have been. As such it is now running an unsupported version.

As moving to a supported MySQL version is going to take some resource (installations, imports, testing, etc.), we're taking the opportunity to look at our options.

We had been thinking about **MariaDB**, which ticks most of our boxes, however we also want to consider the possibility that we may move our system to the cloud at some point in the future. We have no firm plans in this case.

Are there any candidates from **PostgreSQL**, **MySQL**, **MariaDB**, etc that stand out from the others

- RDBMS
- Will support import from existing MySQL
- Ideally Open Source / Low Cost
- Supported by Cloud platforms (Heroku, AWS, Azure, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Postgres

Postgres ticks all your boxes.

Postgres is the world’s most advanced open-source relational database. It is one of the databases most compliant with the SQL standard. Famed for its reliability and faithfulness in not losing your data. Enterprise-levels of quality, performance, and documentation.

You can import data from MySQL in multiple ways, including bulk data loading.

Drivers available for many programming languages.

Extremely open-source, with its own simple license, of the “do anything you want but sue us” variety. Entirely free-of-cost in all scenarios.

Available now as a cloud service by all vendors you mentioned: [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/), [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/postgresql/), [Digital Ocean](https://try.digitalocean.com/managed-databases-postgresql/), and more.

Much work is underway to make Postgres more and more adaptable to the cloud. Some of the cloud vendors have been hiring key Postgres contributors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I disagree with Basil. Unless there's a real and tangible benefit, I would stick with mySQL. Inevitably, changing from one RDBMS to another will reveal some difference in processing or storage. Don't risk unless there's comparable reward.

So many times I've pushed for "the new shiny" only to have it bite me down the line.

Comment: This isn't simply a case of wanting "the new shiny", It's that the effort involved in moving to the latest MySQL version from where we are presents almost as many potential pitfalls as a wholesale change of RDBMS. Which presents an opportunity to review what is out there, and to look at what we might need in the future (namely cloud)